# new and edit controller actions redirecting to home, 'overwriting existing method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, overwrite

I've got an issue where Rails is for some reason redirecting the new and edit methods to the home page, but the index and show methods are returned fine.

There is nothing special in the controller, or the routes, though I'll include them below.

The error I'm getting is

```
Started GET "/recipes/new" for 192.168.5.46 at 2011-11-07 11:40:06 -0800
  Processing by RecipesController#new as HTML
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Recipe.page.
  SQL (4.0ms)  SHOW TABLES
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method User.page.
  SQL (3.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 2) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 2) LIMIT 1
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method RoleUser.page.
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Role.page.
  Role Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `role_users` ON `roles`.id = `role_users`.role_id WHERE ((`role_users`.user_id = 2))
Completed   in 887ms
Redirected to http://localhost:3000
```

I'm assuming the problem is with this 'overwriting' bit, but I don't know why it is attempting to do that, and then redirecting to home.

my recipes controller is

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
 load_and_authorize_resource
before_filter :require_user
respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.find_all_by_author_id(current_user.id)
  end

  def show
   @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
  return render :text =< 'new recipe'
    @recipe = Recipe.new

  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    @recipe.author_id=current_user.id
    if @recipe.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created recipe."
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render :action =< 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

even the render text on new isn't returning, it goes right to the redirect.

Any ideas why this might be happening and suggestions to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What in method `:require_user`?
If you comment `load_and_authorize_resource` is it work?

Comment: of course! thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that. Now i just have to figure out why autorization isn't working on that page. seems the error is authorization using cancan. thanks